# sqlite.get node js, получить данные и передать их в функцию

Tags: javascript, node.js, база-данных, sqlite3, node-modules

Я пытаюсь написать функцию которая возвращает значение из базы данных

Ожидал что функция вернет userStatus но вывод undefined

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');
const sql = new sqlite3.Database('users.sqlite');
function getuser(id) {
    i = null;
    sql.get("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId=?", id, (err, row) => {
        if (row)
        {
            i = row.userStatus;

        }
        
    });
    return i;
}
console.log(getuser(1))
```

Comment: Дело в том, что `sql.get` асинхронная... Как вариант - воспользоваться промисом.

Comment: Не могли бы подсказать как это сделать? я новичок node js)

Comment: См. мой ответ. Только это не только Нода... Это вообще подход в JS.

Comment: спасибо помогло, ну я использую ноду, поэтому указал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> написать функцию которая возвращает значение из базы данных

Можно сделать вот такой промисный вариант...

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');
const sql = new sqlite3.Database('users.sqlite');

function getuser(id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    sql.get("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId=?", id, (err, row) => {
      if (err) return reject(err)
      const i = row?.userStatus ?? null;
      resolve(i)
    });
  })
}
getuser(1)
  .then(i => console.log(i))
  .catch(console.log)
```